# How to make a expression in function to run only for the first time when function called

Tags: javascript

I want to run this line of code run first time when function called `this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;` and after it when second time function run it should not run

```
downVote(eve){

      this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
      if(this.ristricted === this.totalVote){
              this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
      }else {

       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable to control whether or not to run that line:

```
var downvoted = false;

downVote(eve){

      if(downvoted === false) {
        this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
        downvoted = true;
      }

      if(this.ristricted === this.totalVote){
              this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
      }else {

       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to keep some state (a `calledBefore` or `callCount` property, for example), you can just add a property to the function itself:

```
function downVote(eve){
  if (!downVote.calledBefore) {
    downVote.calledBefore = true;
    // do one-time only stuff here:
    this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
  }
  // do other stuff here:
  if(this.ristricted === this.totalVote){
     this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
  }
}
```

Or you can wrap the function in a closure to hold the state privately:

```
var downVote = (function (){
  var calledBefore = false;
  return function downVote(eve) {
    if (!calledBefore) {
      calledBefore = true;
      // do one-time only stuff here:
      this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
    }
    // do other stuff here:
    if(this.ristricted === this.totalVote){
       this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
    }
  }
})();
```

Demo of the latter:

```js
    var downVote = (function (){
      var calledBefore = false;
      return function downVote(eve) {
        if (!calledBefore) {
          calledBefore = true;
          // do one-time only stuff here:
          console.log("First call");
        }
        // do other stuff here:
        console.log("Called");
      }
    })();

    downVote();
    downVote();
    downVote();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just add another variable to track if the function has been called?

```
this.downVoteCalled = false;

downVote(eve){

  if(!this.downVoteCalled){
    this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
    this.downVoteCalled = true; 
  }

  if(this.ristricted === this.totalVote){
          this.totalVote = this.totalVote - 1;
  }else {

   }
}
```